# saslauthd authentication fails for AD

Tags: centos, active-directory, ldap, sasl

I cannot get saslauthd to work with Active Directory. Here is /etc/saslauthd.conf:

```
ldap_use_sasl: yes
ldap_servers: ldap://ad.example.com
ldap_search_base: OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
ldap_bind_dn: CN=openldap,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
ldap_bind_pw: secret
ldap_filter: (sAMAccountName=%u)
```

After I start saslauthd, I execute:

```
testsaslauthd -u myuser -p mypass
```

This gives me `0: NO "authentication failed"`. I thought maybe the problem is with connection to ldap, so I did an ldap search:

```
 ldapsearch -h 172.16.0.4 -x -W -D "cn=openldap,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -b "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" "(sAMAccountName=myuser)"
```

Entered password for the bind user and it gave me the information. For some reason SASL doesn authenticate with LDAP.

What is the reason behind it? What other things can I check?

Comment: Can you try: `testsaslauthd -u myuser -p mypass -s smtp`?

Comment: Authentication failed. No luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

What CentOS vecrsion are you using? In 7.1, there is [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1154566) that prevents authentication against AD servers, but it is fixed and should land in updates in some weeks.

Comment: I switched from Cyrus to Dovecot and Simple Authentication (no SASL) also doesn't work. The bug is specific to Cyrus yet it still doesn't work